# What topological principle is at work here?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is inspired by a problem I discovered in *Putnam and Beyond*, #470, pg. 142:

> Does there exist a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that assumes every element of its range an even (finite) number of times?

The answer is yes, and they provide a caricature of a solution on pg. 542:

[image: Graph of solution.]

This solution consists of infinitely many linear segments in the neighborhood of 0.  One can prove that any solution must have infinitely many local extrema.

As I was thinking about this problem, I noticed that it depends delicately on the domain. If the domain were the circle $S^1$, then much simpler solutions exist, e.g. $e^{i\theta} \mapsto \cos(2\theta)$.

[image: Graph of easy solution for circle domain.]

Similarly, if the domain were a union of two disjoint intervals $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$, then $x\mapsto \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2$ works.

[image: Easy solution for union of two closed intervals.]

If the domain were a single half-open interval $[0,1)$, then $\cos(4\pi x)$ works.

[image: Easy solution for half-open domain.]

**Question:  Is there a topological characterization of which domains admit "easy" solutions to this problem?**

Commentary:

- I leave open the question of what constitutes an "easy" solution, although I've noticed that "piecewise monotonic with finitely many monotone segments" suffices to distinguish all the examples above.
- My hazy intuition for this problem is that there is a sort of parity to 1D domains, with a closed interval having odd parity, a point having odd parity, a circle having even parity, unions have parity equal to the sum of the components, etc.
- I conjecture a generalization of this problem to higher dimensional spaces $X$ might be to consider maps $X\rightarrow X$ which hit each point in the domain an even number of times.

Comment: Re: the second bullet point, it sounds like for nice enough domains, the Euler characteristic is relevant.

Comment: There seems to be a relationship with fixed points. Domain $[0,1]$ has a Brouwer fixed point theorem, while all the examples of "easy" solution you gave, have not.

Comment: This question has now been answered on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462580/what-topological-principle-is-at-work-here